# Excel 2010 VBA: Insert blank cells based on comparison of two adjacent cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have two linked lists that I need to sort. For simplicity of testing, I'm just using 13 items in each list with names of poets and scientists. My real spreadsheet has thousands of entries.

If the values in `second_col` and `third_col` (columns B and C here, respectively) are the same, I want them (and the name that goes with them) to be displayed on the same line. If the value in B is less than the value in C, I want blank cells put in C and D to move that larger value and its associated scientist name down. If the value in C is less than the value in B, I want blank cells in A and B.

What I start with is in columns A-D...what I expect is in columns F-I...and what I get is in columns K-N.

[image]

Here's the code I used to do this task:

```
Sub InsrtFBlnk()

Dim first_col As Range
Dim second_col As Range
Dim row As Integer

Set first_col = Range("A1:A26")
Set second_col = Range("B1:B26")
Set third_col = Range("C1:C26")
Set fourth_col = Range("D1:D26")

'Assuming no headers, so start at row 1 and go to 2-times the original length of the lists
For row = 1 To second_col.Rows.Count
    'Only compare and insert if both cells in second_col and third_col are not blank
    If Not (second_col.Cells(row, 1).Value = "" Or third_col.Cells(row, 1).Value = "") Then
        'If value in 2nd_col is greater than value in 3rd_col, insert blanks in 1st & 2nd cols
        If second_col.Cells(row, 1).Value > third_col.Cells(row, 1).Value Then
            second_col.Cells(row, 1).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            first_col.Cells(row, 1).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
        'If value in 2nd_col is less than value in 3rd_col, insert blanks in 3rd & 4th cols
        If second_col.Cells(row, 1).Value < third_col.Cells(row, 1).Value Then
            third_col.Cells(row, 1).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            fourth_col.Cells(row, 1).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    'If either of the cells in 2nd_col or 3rd_col were blank, come here, end, and go to next row
    Else: End If
Next row

End Sub
```

I honestly expected this to work just the way I commented it up...but clearly it isn't.
I've tried every test in the If Not line I can think of...IsEmpty, using or not using .Value at the end...I'm out of ideas at this point.

Can anyone help me?

Jack H

## ===================

Here is what I was trying to improve. This code works if column A and B are both sorted and everything in B is somewhere in A.
Before: [2-column sorting, Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLi56.jpg)

It works, and here is the after
After: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WKxe.jpg)

I've also expanded it to add spaces if there is a 3rd, 4th, 5th, etc. columns that have to remain on the same line as the number in column B.

I thought the modifications I made would make this work the same way if there were numbers in the first comparison column that weren't in the second comparison column. But clearly, I didn't take something into account.

Comment: "for simplicity sake" huh? Must be Sunday night.  - Anyhow, please share more information and examples of the tests that you tried, to give a better picture of where you're at.

Comment: I'm not sure what further information you need, but everything I've tried in the "make sure they both have something in them" line has resulted in the stuff shown in the image in columns K-N.

Comment: Have done you a version 2 using your logic. Not sure why someone voted my original down as did work :-(

Comment: I just got done with some other projects and got back to this...and your "Version 2" below works.
Thanks! And thanks for using my logic so I can hopefully understand and modify it in the future if the need arises!
I gave you an upvote (but since I'm new, it says it records it but doesn't actually show the change in value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. I am outputting to columns F:I

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ReplaceValues1()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim arr(), sList As Object, dictPoet As Object, dictScientist As Object, dictFinalScientist As Object, i As Long, currCell As Range

        arr = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
        Set sList = CreateObject("System.Collections.Sortedlist")
        Set dictPoet = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Set dictScientist = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Set dictFinalScientist = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            If Not sList.Contains(arr(i, 2)) Then sList.Add arr(i, 2), arr(i, 1)
            If Not sList.Contains(arr(i, 3)) Then sList.Add arr(i, 3), arr(i, 4)
            If Not dictFinalScientist.exists(arr(i, 3)) Then dictFinalScientist.Add arr(i, 3), arr(i, 4)
        Next i

        For i = 0 To sList.Count - 1
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(sList.GetKey(i), Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, 0, 2), 0)) Then
                dictPoet.Add sList.GetByIndex(i), sList.GetKey(i) 'name, number
            Else
                dictPoet.Add "rem_" & sList.GetKey(i), "rem_" & sList.GetKey(i)
            End If
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(sList.GetKey(i), Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, 0, 3), 0)) Then
                dictScientist.Add sList.GetByIndex(i), sList.GetKey(i) 'name, number
            Else
                dictScientist.Add "rem_" & sList.GetKey(i), "rem_" & sList.GetKey(i) 'number, name
            End If
        Next i

        .Cells(1, "F").Resize(dictPoet.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dictPoet.keys)
        .Cells(1, "G").Resize(dictPoet.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dictPoet.Items)
        .Cells(1, "H").Resize(dictPoet.Count, 1) = Application.Transpose(dictScientist.Items)

        For Each currCell In .Cells(1, "I").Resize(dictPoet.Count, 1)
            If Not IsEmpty(currCell.Offset(, -1)) Then currCell = dictFinalScientist(currCell.Offset(, -1).Value)
        Next currCell

       .Range("F1:I1").Resize(dictPoet.Count, 4).Replace ("rem_*"), vbNullString, xlWhole
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

**Running code:**

[image: Testrun]

**Version 2:**

Using your logic

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub InsrtFBlnk()

    Dim first_col As Range
    Dim second_Col As Range
    Dim row As Long
    Dim third_col As Range, fourth_col As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set first_col = .Range("A1:A26")
        Set second_Col = .Range("B1:B26")
        Set third_col = .Range("C1:C26")
        Set fourth_col = .Range("D1:D26")

        For row = 1 To second_Col.Rows.Count  
            If Not (second_Col.Cells(row, 1).Value = vbNullString Or third_col.Cells(row, 1).Value = vbNullString) Then
                If second_Col.Cells(row, 1).Value > third_col.Cells(row, 1).Value Then
                    first_col.Cells(row, 1).Resize(, 2).Select
                    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                ElseIf second_Col.Cells(row, 1).Value < third_col.Cells(row, 1).Value Then
                    third_col.Cells(row, 1).Resize(, 2).Select
                    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                End If
            End If
        Next row
    End With

End Sub
```

I am wondering if you may be using columns that are spaced apart in which case you might need to union the columns before insert as below:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub InsrtFBlnk()

    Dim first_col As Range
    Dim second_Col As Range
    Dim row As Long
    Dim third_col As Range, fourth_col As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set first_col = .Range("A1:A26")
        Set second_Col = .Range("B1:B26")
        Set third_col = .Range("C1:C26")
        Set fourth_col = .Range("D1:D26")

        For row = 1 To second_Col.Rows.Count
            If Not (second_Col.Cells(row, 1).Value = vbNullString Or third_col.Cells(row, 1).Value = vbNullString) Then
                If second_Col.Cells(row, 1).Value > third_col.Cells(row, 1).Value Then
                    Union(first_col.Cells(row, 1), second_Col.Cells(row, 1)).Select
                    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                ElseIf second_Col.Cells(row, 1).Value < third_col.Cells(row, 1).Value Then
                    Union(third_col.Cells(row, 1), fourth_col.Cells(row, 1)).Select
                    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                End If
            End If
        Next row
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) When I try to run this on my file, I get an error message,

Comment: 1) When I try to run this on my file, I get an error message,
"Runtime error '13'"
Type mismatch

and when I debug, it highlights the first line of code,
arr = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

2) This is so different from what I was trying to do (which is modified from something that worked on two columns when the values in one column were always equal to or greater than the other) that I don't understand it enough to even try to debug it.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to run code. I also used the step-into debugger (F8) and I get the runtime error every time it gets to that line of code.

Comment: Is your data laid out as shown? My code does **exactly** what you have shown in terms  of input to output. Observe the .gif

Comment: Yes, my data is laid out exactly as shown in the image I attached and it seems to match what you have.

Are you using Excel 2010? Your menus look slightly different than mine, I wonder if that might be part of the reason it isn't working for me?

Comment: I don't think so. The only thing I might have thought would be a problem is the SortedList which requires .Net framework. But your error is before this.

Comment: If you change Dim arr() to Dim arr As Variant then run? Would be good to understand this in case comes up again.

Comment: I already tried explicitly setting the array definition to "As Variant" and I get the same thing. 
I'm trying to get a gif of what happens with mine...I don't see anything different, but maybe you will.

Comment: What happens if you drop the .Value and have   Dim arr As Variant, sList As Object, dictPoet As Object, dictScientist As Object, dictFinalScientist As Object, i As Long, currCell As Range
        
        arr = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion

Comment: Very strange. Can you upload a workbook without macros i.e. xlsx ? https://uploadfiles.io/

Comment: Also, have you tried substituting the actual range address in e.g. A1:D13 instead of the currentregion?

Comment: The other thing is that I want to be able to adapt this to other files I might get in the future that could have five or six columns that have to change based on the comparison of any two of them. So I'd really prefer to know what's going wrong with the code I wrote rather than having somebody just write something new (and incomprehensible to me) for me.

Comment: I updated my original post with the original VBA I was trying to improve. It works as long as everything in the 2nd comparison column is in the 1st comparison column. I thought adding a symmetrical test to add spaces when the value in the first wasn't in the second would work...but clearly there's something I don't know about VBA programming and scalability.

Thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: I have written you  version 2. See the bottom version.